# How do I limit the movement of an object to two directions?

Tags: rigging, objects, constraints, snapping

I'm trying to get a 'rigged' mechanical arm to move in 2 certain directions:

[image: Screenshot]

Some other objects in my Blend-file are able to go in a certain direction using transform constraints.

But this won't work for the 'thing' I'm trying to achieve now (the blue object should not rotate):

[image: Schematic]

The reason I want it to be locked is because I'm using a rigging menu made out of limited location constraints:

[image: Rigging Menu]

The 'Red line in the middle' doesn't have to be there necessarily. I used it to explain it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correctly, what you want to do in the picture with the U-shaped path can be achieved with a "Clamp to" constraint. **(If you are familiar with drivers, then first see the EDIT below!!!)** For this you clamp your Object that has to follow a curve-Object. The follower Object should then only be translatable along that set Path. Of course you could then have some other constraint move that path around if you want ;)

The result should look something like this:[image]

And here an example for using additional constraints on the curve, where the curve copies the z-location of the blue cube: [image]

To do make the red cube go along the full path when the blue cube is moved you can use drivers. By the clamp to constraint the red object moves along the entire path only by manual transform alon the x-axis. So you could add a driver (rightclick-> add driver) to the the x-Location of the red cube and make the "input variable" the z-location of the blue cube. Then the result looks like this:[image]

**EDIT:  If you want to move that curve around in all directions, then the "follow path" constraint is much more stable. Just make a driver on the Offset, make the input variable whatever you want and you're done!**

Happy Blending!

Comment: The other constraints you mentioned, which ones would you suggest because I can't figure out how to move it around?

Comment: I added an example to my answer. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Not exactly. I don't know if it is possible, but I'd like to have the object follow the entire curve (as in your first image) by only moving the controller up. (See my 3th image) In other words have the object go from the Start to the Finish: right > up > left.

Comment: I'm not sure which object you call controller... Although what you describe in text sounds like you could use a "driver" to control the position on the curve by somehow moving an object...

Comment: Thank you. I will look further into this method.

Comment: I added a section about drivers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95883/discussion-between-kenzy-vergauwen-and-robert-roth).